# Why are flights for shorter trips more expensive than for long ones?

Tags: air-travel

Lufthansa charges me almost double the price for departing and returning flights, if they are only one day apart, than if I would stay yet another day or two.

Why is this? I find this extremely annoying, because now I need to balance additional hotel costs for a longer stay with this silly pricing system.

Comment: Airfare pricing is a pandora's box, but this one is likely due to "short trips = business traveler", and business traveler care much less about prices

Comment: @helm Going there for a late exam at my exchange university and this honestly makes me rethink my image of this airline. First they get billions of taxpayers money and then they pull tricks like this on you... How to scare off future customers 101.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum I've stayed an extra day or two in the hotel and had it still work out cheaper than an earlier flight, even after factoring in meals!  Unfortunately the amount I spent on sight-seeing probably did me in

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum it shouldn’t alter your image of *this airline*, in particular. Almost the entire (non-budget) airline industry does it.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum, airlines are businesses, not public services. The idea of a business is to _maximize profit_, not to please its customers; the latter is only a side target, if it helps the main target.

Comment: Is it the time between the trips, or is it just that you are travelling on days with higher demand?